# Report viewer control - generate different sized graphs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services

I am building a web application using sql server reporting services. As part of my application, I present the report onwards to the end user using the report viewer control.

The reports that I have created are mostly very squeezed. That means that I have several graphs on the same single report.

What I want to do, is give the user the ability to focus on a single report. I've created the appropriate client side code, though now I am faced with a rather tedious problem. The image that the report reviewer renders is relatively small (as I needed to fit several graphs on the same single report). when I try enlarging the graph's image on the client side, it gets stretched. The image is rendered small!

How can I instruct SSRS to create a bigger image of the graph? Can I specify anything in the underlying querystring?

```
http://localhost:3450/Reporter.aspx/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=rkymfk45wv0wosrpru5en4rr&Culture=1037&CultureOverrides=True&UICulture=1033&UICultureOverrides=True&ReportStack=2&ControlID=bc66e58c31d64e8a8231389d9a5b5fdd&OpType=ReportImage&IterationId=163e91e9a63e45adbc03658d347470ab&StreamID=C_59iT1_1
```

Thank you

Comment: @Eddy, you are correct. Will do. I tried specifying the details I thought that will be of interest. What is lacking?

Comment: What is the purpose of providing "http://localhost" link?

Comment: It is the link that is used to recieve the images from the reporting services

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say but there are few third party tools that can offer the dynamic ZOOM capability, I think. http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Silverlight-Viewer-for-Reporting-Services.aspx?lang=en fyi

Comment: Is there any way to do it in asp.net without using silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anyway to dynamically size a report element.  I don't think you can use expressions for height and width.

Why not have one report that is all of the small graphs, then make single reports for the larger graphs.  You can then set the navigation of the small charts to "Jump to report" and go to the larger charts.  It is ugly, because you will have to maintain two copies of the charts, but it should work.

Comment: because if I have 25 reports, and in each report I have 5 graphs, it would mean 25 * 5 = ... it's too much